# What are the proper stockpile settings for a butcher shop?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I assume I want raw meat, fat, and tallow, but what else? Bones? Teeth? Hair? Corpses? Also, where can I find all these things in the custom stock pile settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two stockpiles that the end products of a butcher shop feed into. These are [food](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Refuse_stockpile#Food) and [refuse](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Refuse_stockpile#Refuse) stockpiles.

While it is possible to specify individually every item allowed into your stockpile, this would be a massive pain because many of the animal body parts (as mentioned in the food stockpile entry) are different per animal. So it would not be a matter of including "fat" as an allowed item in a stockpile; it would require setting "horse fat", "dog fat", "dragon fat", etc. inside the stockpile settings.

Do not despair. There is an easier way to handle this problem. Simply set a stockpile to accept any kind of food and/or refuse, but then [link](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Refuse_stockpile#Take_from_a_stockpile.2Fworkshop) it to your production butcher shop(s) (use the <kbd>q</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> command from the stockpile and select your butcher shop). Finally set the stockpile to only take (accept) from links (the <kbd>a</kbd> command from the <kbd>q</kbd> menu for the stockpile), and then it will only be filled with items from your butcher workshop. This stockpile's only job is to accept everything from the butcher's workshop.

Warning: Make sure you either link both a refuse and a food stockpile to your butcher shop, or else make a single custom stockpile that does both, because anything that will not fit into the linked stockpile(s) will be stuck in the butcher's workshop.

Comment: What about stockpiles for the inputs to a butcher shop? `Refuse` > `Corpses` + `Body parts`? Only some item types?

Comment: The issue with inputs for a butcher shop is that they also take live animals as an input. I have not tested if setting an input linkage interferes with this. Other than that, those are the correct settings. Or at least they will get the job done. http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Butcher%27s_shop#Hauling_and_stockpile_considerations